# Can an iOS app send HTTP requests when not visible?

Tags: ios, operating-system, httprequest, limits

I have an issue with an iOS development company that claims the app they are building for us cannot keep sending HTTP requests to our back-end with a timer when not visible (e.g. as soon as I press the home button or go check my emails) due to operating system limitations.

Is it true or are they being lazy?

I understand if the app gets removed from memory whenever memory is needed by other apps after a while, but no request being made at all as soon as we go check our emails or show the home screen, really?

So to put my question clearly: When is a regular (non-VOIP app) limited by the iOS operating system in the execution of its code and sending of requests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can register the app for background processing, at which point the OS will wake the app up periodically and it can then run the http requests BUT you cannot control the schedule on which the app will be woken to do its thing as the OS optimizes based on usage patterns, battery levels, network availability, etc.